# How to properly handle Axis2 generated exceptions with a REST client

Tags: apache-axis

I am using Axis2 v1.6.1 and Resty as a rest client.  If I purposely send a malformed request that Axis2 cannot parse, for example, sending "p=0.0" where p is an Integer, then Axis2 will generate 500 HTTP Response and log an error in it's log saying something to the effect of:

[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method createUpdateOrganization
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid value "0.0" for element poStart

...

This is great but I need to be able to capture this exception information in order to act upon it as part of our exception management framework.

It seems to be throwing an AxisFault exception but this is before it reaches my service so I'm not sure what I need to configure in order to get this information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article:

http://www.packtpub.com/article/handler-and-phase-in-apache-axis

Which explains exactly what I need to do.  The answer is to create a custom handler for the InFaultFlow phase. :)   I hope this helps somebody else!